# Is there a way to generate PDF from specific HTML elements with CSS using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to generate a PDF (as an A4 page) from a specific div in my HTML page along with it's style. Is there a way to do that without using addStyleTag? There is a lot of style and addStyleTag simply won't work.

Thank you.